# Getting an error in Android: "Failed to instantiate class step"

Tags: android, appium, driver

This is the error that I am getting when executing. I've been trying to get @AndroidFindBy to take me and it appeared that the driver was null and now I get this error. How can I solve it?

Here's the error:

```
Step failed
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class step.IngresosMyDemonAPP
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:67)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
    at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:56)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:84)
    at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:75)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$6(Runtime.java:107)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runTestCase$5(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.executeAndThrow(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:23)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runTestCase(CucumberExecutionContext.java:137)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$executePickle$7(Runtime.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(Runtime.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$runFeatures$3(Runtime.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.runFeatures(Runtime.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.lambda$run$0(Runtime.java:78)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.lambda$runFeatures$6(CucumberExecutionContext.java:148)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.execute(CucumberExecutionContext.java:163)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.runFeatures(CucumberExecutionContext.java:146)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:78)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at io.cucumber.core.backend.DefaultObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at pages.myDemonApp.<init>(myDemonApp.java:22)
```

This is the class steps:

```
package step;


import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import pages.myDemonApp;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;


public class IngresosMyDemonAPP {
    AndroidDriver driver;
    myDemonApp mydemonapp = new myDemonApp(driver);

    @Given("Cuando ingreso al aplicativo MyDemonAPP")
    public void cuandoIngresoAlAplicativoMyDemonAPP() throws MalformedURLException {
        mydemonapp.configuracionMobile();
    }

    @When("Me encuentro en el home del aplicativo")
    public void meEncuentroEnElHomeDelAplicativo() {
        mydemonapp.abrirMenu();
    }
}
```

This is the class when I capture elements:

```
package pages;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumBy;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AndroidFindBy;
import io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import step.IngresosMyDemonAPP;

public class myDemonApp {
   public AndroidDriver driver;
   myDemonApp mydemonapp = new myDemonApp(driver);
   IngresosMyDemonAPP ingresomydemonapp = new IngresosMyDemonAPP();

    public myDemonApp(AndroidDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
    }



    public void configuracionMobile() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName","Pixel 4 API 28");
        cap.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        cap.setCapability("app","C:\\Users\\Jooao\\Desktop\\Joao\\PrimerEjemplo\\src\\main\\aplicacion\\Android-MyDemoAppRN.1.3.0.build-244.apk");
        cap.setCapability("udid","emulator-5554");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion","9");
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }

    @AndroidFindBy(xpath = "//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"open menu\"]")
    public WebElement openMenu;

    @AndroidFindBy (xpath = "(//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"store item\"])[3]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.ImageView")
    public WebElement clicLoginMenu;


    public void abrirMenu(){
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            openMenu.click();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@content-desc=\"open menu\"]")).click();
        }

    public void presionarLoginMenu(){
        clicLoginMenu.click();
    }

 }
```